# how do you center a custom UINavigation Bar Image

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

So I have an navigation bar I would like to customize and center no matter what I do I either get the image tiling like [so](http://myusuf3.dropmark.com/78530/1294463).

Here is the code i am using to set the `self.navigation.titleView` in my `UITableControllerView`

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [self titleView]; // happens in viewDidLoad

- (UIView *)titleView{
UIImage *headerImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header@2x"];
UIImageView *containerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, headerImage.size.width, headerImage.size.height)];


return containerView;

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You would have to set the frame of containerView accordingly.For e.g.: the y-origin will be ceilf((height of navigationBar-height of your image)/2.0f) and similarly, x-origin ill be ceilf((width of navigationBar-width of your image)/2.0f)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *imgtitle = [[UIImageView alloc]    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25)];
    [imgtitle setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imgtitle;
    imgtitle.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
```

Comment: Try this [containerView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];